# neo4j relationship creating multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and been trying things.

I created two nodes successfully

```
CREATE (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 })
CREATE (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 })
```

With this command:

```
CREATE (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john)
```

ends up successful but creates two other nodes with different `id`s.

So, I end up with 4 nodes.

Comment: You may want to look to the MERGE clause http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers for nodes and relationships are only meaningful within a single Cypher query. If you had combined your two queries into one, then `sally` and `john` would not have been re-created:

```
CREATE (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 })
CREATE (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 })
CREATE (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john);
```

If you really needed to have 2 separate queries, your second query would have to find the `sally` and `john` nodes before re-using them. You new query could also use some different identifiers for them (like `a` and `b`):

```
CREATE (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 })
CREATE (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 })
```

```
MATCH (a:Person { name: 'Sally'}), (b:Person { name: 'John'})
CREATE (a)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(b);
```

*In the second query, I assume that a `Person` node's `name` is sufficient to find a unique node.*